# ElasticSearch: conditional filter based on field value

Tags: elasticsearch

The task sounds quite simple:
if document field equals specific value, add filter, otherwise not filter is applied.

F.x. get all fruits from warehouse but if fruit.type is apple get them delivered 7 days ago.

Is that possible to do on elastic level?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do this in elassticsearch using [Nesting Boolean Queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/combining-filters.html#_nesting_boolean_queries) with some [range](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_ranges.html)-sugar and [date-math](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#date-math)-magic.

Since you didn't post your mapping or some sample data I will just use the following data:

```
curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/testing/foo/ -d '{ "fruit" : "orange", "delivered" : "2016-04-22"}'
curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/testing/foo/ -d '{ "fruit" : "banana", "delivered" : "2016-03-22"}'
curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/testing/foo/ -d '{ "fruit" : "orange", "delivered" : "2016-04-12"}'
curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/testing/foo/ -d '{ "fruit" : "apple", "delivered" : "2016-04-12"}'
curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/testing/foo/ -d '{ "fruit" : "apple", "delivered" : "2016-04-20"}'
```

Then the following query will do what you want:

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/testing/foo/_search" -d'
{
  "query": {
    "constant_score": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "bool": {
                "must_not": {
                  "term": {
                    "fruit": "apple"
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "fruit": "apple"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "range": {
                      "delivered": {
                        "lt": "now-7d"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

In SQL this roughly translate to:

```
WHERE fruit <> 'apple' OR (fruit = 'apple' AND delivered < Now-7d)
```